# GetItemAtposition returns object rather than String

Tags: android, onitemlongclicklistener

I am using OnItemLongClickListener with ListView. I want to copy the text of the ListView when pressed for the long time. However, it returns the object id instead of String Value. I am getting value of string as com.myapplication.smnotif.NotificationEntry@42ba0898 etc... I need value of the String...

The code is as follows -

```
    mListViewNotification = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notification_listview);
    mListViewNotification.setAdapter(mNotifAdapter);
    mListViewNotification.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mListViewNotification.setLongClickable(true);
    mListViewNotification
            .setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                        View arg1, int pos, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) getApplicationContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    String string = (String) mListViewNotification
                            .getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Label", string);
                    cm.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what toString returns if you don't override it to return something more meaningful.  Either override toString() to return the string you want, or even better write a new function to do it.  You generally only use toString() if the string accurately sums up the totality of the object's state.

Comment: Gabe,Can you please elaborate more on that? I am still unable to get the solution to the issue. A small code snipped will be helpful...

Comment: You have to either override NotificationEntry.toString() to return the data you want, or you need to write a new function on it that returns the string.  If you do not override the toString function, that's what the default behavior is.